# How to check if a block exists in a twig template - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Imagine I have something like this in my twig template

```
{% block posLeft %}
   -----
{%endblock%}
```

Is there any way to check for existance of the posLeft block without calling to:

```
block("posLeft")
```

And check the return value of the posBlock to varify the existance. I am a newbie in Symfony2 + Twig.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Seems to me that you're adding logic into your views that probably belongs in your controller. If you want to display certain content based on some variable then simply inject that variable into your view and then display different blocks as needed.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can solve it like this, if you want to display a certain block only if it has content. Hope, this is what you're looking for.

**Example index.html.twig**

```
{% set _block = block('dynamic') %}
{% if _block is not empty %}
    {{ _block|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

**Example part.html.twig**

```
{% extends "index.html.twig" %}

{% block dynamic %}
    Block content goes here.
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there no built in tag for this ? getting block value and check it again an empty string require a lot of code. It looks really ugly.

Comment: I don't think that there's another way. And as @lifo said, you are probably putting to much logic into your templates. Be aware to not put this 2-line statement into a one-line check, as this can cause new sub-requests. Here's a similar discussion on the Twig Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twig-users/FHDTknu5n2M

Answer (score 20):

You can do it like this:

```
{% if block('posLeft') %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

**But it is not efficient** if you need output of rendered block. 
So **if you will need block output you should assign it to variable in the first place** 
and then do assertions

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way!

Comment: Downvoted. See link in comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774384/how-to-check-if-a-block-exist-in-twig-template-symfony2#comment19015938_13806784

Comment: For me there where sometimes spaces in the "empty" block (because of formating). So i sloved it by using: if block('posLeft') | trim != ''

Answer (score 18):

The other answers here do not work for twig 2.1 (I've not tested on ~2.0), so here's a small update:

```
{% if block('dynamic') is defined %}
    {{ block('dynamic')|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

Note that the line to render the block is **not**:

```
{% block dynamic %}
    {#  this wont work  #}
{% endblock %}
```

This wont work because the block will be rendered during compile, and so the test will return true that it exists (as its tested at runtime). So you need to render the block with `{{ block('dynamic')|raw }}` instead as this doesn't actually define the block in the template.

Comment: The `|raw` is superfluous here, since using `block('dynamic')` already handles escaping and it is not being set to a variable first before being displayed.

Answer (score 15):

First check, which Twig version you are using inside your Symfony project, because the answers here are only for Twig 1.

**If you are using Twig 2** you are lucky. According to the Twig documentation, you can use the defined test to check if the block exists in the current template context.

```
{% if block("dynamic") is defined %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

I have written a little TwigExtension to check if the block gets called inside the if statement and it seems like Twig only really checks if the block exists and does not call it.

The link to the docs: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html

**If you are using Twig 1**, the old answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806784/6458657 is still correct.

Answer (score 9):

Twig 2.x

```
{{ (block("posLeft")) ?? '' }}
```

If you want to display a block if it's defined or not in one line.  Might be a little kludgy but satisfies my needs without a bunch of if..then logic.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to provide another example which worked for me.

```
<body
{%  if block('ngapp') is not empty  %}ng-app="{% block ngapp %}{% endblock %}"{% endif %}
>
```

This allows me in child templates declare `{% block ngapp 'myApp' %}` and have it displayed within parent.

This was needed  because on some pages I was bootstrapping Angular manually via (`angular.bootstrap('moduleName', rootElement)`) and Angular does not like empty `ng-app=''` directive and breaks in weird ways.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me in Twig 3.3.10, throwing an error that the block wasn't defined.

To solve this and define a block whose contents are conditionally wrapped in a container, only if any block content is set, this worked:

### Parent template with block definition and wrapper element

```
{# parent.twig #}

<h1>Hello. I am the parent.</h1>

{% if block('sidebar') is not empty %}                                 
  <div class="sidebar-container">                                               
    {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}                                  
  </div>                                                                    
{% endif %}
```

### Child template setting block content

```
{% extends 'parent.twig' %}

{% block sidebar %}
  Sidebar content from child template
{% endblock %}
```

Output – block content inside wrapper:

```html
<h1>Hello. I am the parent.</h1>

<div class="sidebar-container">
  Sidebar content from child template
</div>
```

### Child template not setting block content

```
{% extends 'parent.twig' %}

{# sidebar block not set in this one... #}
```

Output – no empty wrapper element:

```html
<h1>Hello. I am the parent.</h1>
```

Comment: This works but with some caveats.  `{% if block('sidebar') is not empty %} ` already renders that block in memory . So when you later use `{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}`  it performs rendering once more. Not only it is a performance hit (albeit minor in most cases) but it will also throw an error if block sidebar renders a symfony form type (as by default form type fields cannot be rendered twice).