# How to check if a block is overridden in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to check whether a block is overriden in a child template.

`template.html.twig`:

```
<html>
    ...
    <nav class="menu">
        {% block menu %}
        {% endblock %}
    </nav>
    ...
    <div class="contents">
        {% block contents %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

`page1.html.twig` -- contains a menu:

```
{% extends '::template.html.twig' %}

{% block menu %}
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
    Hello World!
{% endblock %}
```

`page2.html.twig` -- does not contain a menu:

```
{% extends '::template.html.twig' %}

{% block contents %}
    Hello World!
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to show the `nav` element in the template, only if it is overriden in the child template (the goal is to avoid an empty `<nav />` element).

The Twig syntax has a `is empty` test, but it only applies to variables, not blocks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774384/how-to-check-if-a-block-exist-in-twig-template-symfony2

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable in your child template check for that:

```
{# template.html.twig #}

{% if show_menu is not empty %}
<nav class="menu">
    {% block menu %}
    {% endblock %}
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

```
{# page1.html.twig #}

{% set show_menu = true %}
```

Maybe you should also consider putting this markup in the block definition for a more straight-forward approach.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do that without using such tricks. Maybe we aren't taking the problem in the right way...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a wrapper to your nav element and then override it in page2 to make it blank when you don't want a menu. This doesn't require an extra variable.

**template.html.twig**

```
... snip ...
{% block nav %}
<nav class="menu">
    {% block menu %}
    {% endblock %}
</nav>
{% endblock %}
... snip ...
```

**page2.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::template.html.twig' %}

{% block nav '' %} {# here's the kicker ... #}

{% block contents %}
    Hello World!
{% endblock %}
```

In any other page that has a menu you would continue to override the 'menu' block normally.