# Combining optional block with element in twig

Tags: twig

In defining a base template in twig, I want to reserve an area for special notifications, using a block. It could be an extra sidebar that may contain all kinds of things (calendar, or some extra information, whatever.) The default should be emtpy, but any child template may extend and fill it.

Now I want to have all those extensions be included in a `<div class='special-sidebar'>` if the block is extended, and not show anything if it is not included. Is there any way to define the containing element in the base template?

```
{# Base template #}    
Content etc...
{% block special %} {# may be overridden by child template #}{% endblock %}

{# child template #}
{% block special %} Here, the special sidebar is filled! {% endblock %}
```

The base page should show just the content:

```
// base template:
Content etc...
```

And the child page:

```
// child template
Content etc...
<div class"special-sidebar"> Here, the special sidebar is filled! </div>
```

Where and how do I put the html for this? I could define it in every child, but that means you have to remember to use the correct html each time, I'd rather set this in the base template and not bother with it. But I don't want empty elements in my page if the block is not overridden.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774384/how-to-check-if-a-block-exist-in-twig-template-symfony2

Comment: I think it is! Sad that there isn't a way to do it a bit more elegantly, because I think someone coming along afterwards will have some difficulty grasping it immediately, but thanks!

Comment: Ill add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it like this, if you want to display a certain block only if it has content. Hope, this is what you're looking for.

**Example index.html.twig**

```
{% set _block = block('dynamic') %}
{% if _block is not empty %}
    {{ _block|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

**Example part.html.twig**

```
{% extends "index.html.twig" %}

{% block dynamic %}
    Block content goes here.
{% endblock %}
```

**Source:** [How to check if a block exists in a twig template - Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774384/how-to-check-if-a-block-exist-in-twig-template-symfony2?lq=1)